# Send Mail from Local Pc to other domains

Tags: java, email, smtp, localhost

I have a program send some reports to technical person in my company. Program working succesfully but sometimes firewall block communicates between Machine which working my program and Mail Server. So reports can't delivered to users.

I am using apache common mail for sending mails in Java like below;

```
public void sendMail(ArrayList importants) throws Exception {
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("Company Mail Server Domain Here");
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthentication("example@companydomain","pass");
email.setSSLOnConnect(false);
email.setFrom("example@companydomain");
email.setSubject("New Important List");
email.setMsg("New Important List;\n"+importants);
email.addTo("receiver1@companydomain");
email.addTo("receiver2@companydomain");
email.send();
}
```

Below code working succesfully and deliver necessary list to users. But as i said above sometimes firewall block communication between Machine & Mail Server and i cant authenticate.

I plan when mail.companyname.com not responsible i can try send mail via localhost SMTP service like a spammers. Because these lists are critic and must be delivered to releated persons. I have to be sure users informed if any list prepared by Program.

Is it possbile?

Thanks.

Comment: Before you can make progress you must understand more clearly why _"sometimes firewall block communication between Machine & Mail Server"_.  You will have to update your post to include the specific error messages you are seeing.  Sending mail directly from your localhost will almost surely not work.

Comment: @JimGarrison I dont have any specific erros message. Java application work with infinite loop. Just some informations compiled and sending to releated users via mail. When i cant receive any mails about 4-5 hours i debug the whole code and i cant reach any spesific error messages in sendMail method. Than i restart the firewall between Machine and Mail Server. Applications start send the mails. I dont know why firewall block my machine :(

Comment: How do you _know_ your are blocked by a firewall?

Comment: When i restart the firewall device, mails start coming from application to my mailbox.

Comment: Sounds like the firewall device is adaptive and is detecting what it believes to be abuse, and blocking the port dynamically.  You need to figure out why that is happening.  Nobody here can help you with that.